# Copy/Paste a listobject in excel lose the attached events

Tags: c#, vsto

Let's create a `ListObject` and attach an event on it as msdn explain here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyfs6478.aspx

**The code**

In an application-level addin, code will look like above:

```
Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);

Excel.Range cell = worksheet.Range["$A$1:$D$4"];
ListObject list1 = worksheet.Controls.AddListObject(cell, "list1");
list1.Selected += list1_SelectedDeselected;
list1.Deselected += list1_SelectedDeselected;
```

With something like that to see the triggered events :

```
private void list1_SelectedDeselected(Excel.Range Target)
{
    Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);

    Excel.Range cell = worksheet.Range["$A$6"];
    if (cell.Value2 == "foo")
    {
        cell.Value2 = "bar";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.Value2 = "foo";
    }
}
```

**Strange behavior**
If you run this code within a add-in in excel, you'll see this and that

[image: The <code>Selected</code> event is triggered]
[image: The <code>Deselected</code> event is triggered]

If you **cut**/paste this table within the same worksheet, every attached events will be triggered.

**But** if you **cut**/paste into another sheet, the events will not be attached anymore to the ListObject.

Are there a reason I don't know for this unpredictable behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another VSTO object to subscribe to the events anew. The GetVstoObject should be used to get a new Worksheet object.

Comment: You say that the actual object wearing the event his the ListObject attached to the sheet, so if I cut the ListObject on runtime to paste it on a new sheet, it is a light copy of the ListObject which is created, so we loose the events. That's it?